# Prove $0a=0$ in a ring (My Solution)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This post is a Q&A style post on this problem from the beginning of Ring Theory:

Prove $0a=0$ in a ring $R$.

Comment: would it be possible to know why my answer was downvoted? :(

Comment: PSQs (mere problem statement questions as one is assigned), alone, with no context as to why you need to ask this, and where you are stuck, never make good questions, regardless of the fact that you proceed to answer the obvious question.)  Please don't proceed to do this with every question you encounter in your Ring Theory class, particularly with review material like this.  Save Q&A when you actually post a question, and after posting it, with context, you arrive at a solution.  Then you can post your solution as an answer.  But this clearly never was an actual question you had too ask.

Answer (score 0):

Using these properties of $R$:

- existence of additive identity in $(R,+)$
- distributivity in $R$

$$0a = (0+0)a = 0a + 0a$$

Then we have

$$0a + (-0a) = 0a + 0a + (-0a)$$

So $$0 = 0a$$